# How can I transform this Backus–Naur Form expression into a Regex (.Net)?

Tags: .net, regex, bnf

The expression is:

```
N | ( 1 { A | B | C | D | E1 | E2 | E3 } )
```

Meaning the descriptor "N" or one or more of the listed descriptors without repetition.

The best I have got is:

```
@"^(N|(A|B|C|D|E1|E2|E3){1,})$"
```

But that does not prevent repetition.

```
@"^(N|(A{0,1}B{0,1}...)$"
```

That prevents repetition but then requires a specific order to the elements, which isn't really OK either.

Any ideas?

(I am not actually sure that the bnf expression itself disallows repetition, but that is what I need.)

Comment: http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/do_NOT_parse_using_regexp.html Use regular expressions to recognize words, not structures.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. But what would I use to recognize this structure? @DavidBrabant
It will be used to validate input of the mentioned form.

Comment: Or is PCRE the method that you are suggesting?

Comment: Depending on the complexity of your "A", "B" ... I would write a descent parser, I think.

Comment: It really isn't that complex at all. (Sorry if my question was badly stated). The user is allowed to input for instance "N", "A", "B" or "AB" but not "AA" or "BB". The letters themselves that is.
Thus the problem is to validate that input. The two regex'es I wrote does partially validate these cases, thought not completely as stated in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can, but it ain't pretty:

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(
    @"^           # Start of string
    (?:           # Either match...
     N            # N
    |             # or...
     (?:          # Match one of the following:
      A(?!.*A)    # A unless followed somewhere later by another A
     |            # or
      B(?!.*B)    # B unless...
     |            # etc. etc.
      C(?!.*C)
     |
      D(?!.*D)
     |
      E1(?!.*E1)
     |
      E2(?!.*E2)
     |
      E3(?!.*E3)
     )+           # one or more times
    )             # End of alternation
    $             # End of string", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

This solution uses [negative lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: Just a question @Tim. What function do the '?:' have? It seems to be working without those two.

Comment: @Daniel: The only difference is that `(...)` is a *capturing* group, meaning that the regex engine stores whatever was matched inside that group in a backreference which you can then refer to later. If you don't need to do that, `(?:...)` works just the same, but without storing that part of the match. Therefore, they are a bit more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's possible even for a .net `Regex` (which is more powerful than the strictest definition of 'regular language') to do this; and anyway, unless you have a requirement to use only a `Regex`, there's nothing wrong (to my mind) with:

```
bool IsValid(string input)
{
    var Ns = input.Count(c => c == 'N');
    var As = input.Count(c => c == 'A');
    // etc
    var E1s = Regex.Matches(input, "E1").Count
    // etc

    var maxDescriptorCount = (new[] { As, ... ,E1s, ... }).Max();

    var isValid = 
        ((Ns == 1) && (maxDescriptorCount == 0))
        ||
        ((Ns == 0) && (maxDescriptorCount == 1))
        ;

    return isValid;
}
```

Is it the shortest code that solves the problem? No. Is it readable and maintainable? I think so.

<sub>(You could write a utility method with the signature `int MaxN(params int[] numbers)` if you wanted)</sub>